# Trigger after update on Table

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I don't know if this has been answered before, I'll try to be as specific as I can.

I have this table

```
TABLE  "MOVIMIENTO_A" 
   (    "COD_MOVIMIENTO" NUMBER, 
    "COD_CUENTA" NUMBER, 
    "COD_T_MOVIMIENTO" NUMBER, 
    "VAL_MOVIMIENTO" NUMBER, 
    "FECHA_MOVIMIENTO" DATE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("COD_MOVIMIENTO")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
```

and this table

```
TABLE  "CUENTA_A" 
   (    "COD_CUENTA" NUMBER, 
    "NOM_CUENTA" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "SAL_CUENTA" NUMBER, 
    "BANDERA_CUENTA" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("COD_CUENTA")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
```

And this is the trigger I have

```
create or replace trigger AUDITO_CUENTA_A
after insert or update or delete on CUENTA_A 
for each row
BEGIN
IF inserting then
INSERT INTO AUDI_CUENTA_A VALUES(:NEW.cod_CUENTA, :NEW.nom_cuenta, :OLD.SAL_CUENTA, :NEW.sal_cuenta, sysdate, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS')); 
END IF;
IF deleting then
INSERT INTO AUDI_CUENTA_A VALUES(:NEW.cod_CUENTA, :NEW.nom_cuenta, :OLD.SAL_CUENTA, :NEW.sal_cuenta, sysdate, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS')); 
END IF;
IF updating then
INSERT INTO AUDI_CUENTA_A VALUES(:NEW.cod_CUENTA, :NEW.nom_cuenta, :OLD.SAL_CUENTA, :NEW.sal_cuenta, sysdate, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS')); 
END IF;
END;
```

So, right now if I make an update on `MOVIMIENTO_A` the trigger fires, but it is only supposed to fire when I make an update on `CUENTA_A` directly, and not when I update `MOVIMIENTO_A`.

I Would really appreciate it if I can get some ideas on how to update my trigger.

Comment: The trigger will only fire if `CUENTA_A` is being modified. Do you have another trigger on `MOVIMIENTO_A` which is modifying `CUENTA_A`?

Comment: I have another trigger on `MOVIMIENTO_A`, which updates `CUENTA_A`, but i need another trigger that if i update `CUENTA_A` but not from `MOVIMIENTO_A` fires up.
I don't know how to paste the trigger on a comment so I'll put the paste.bin link with the trigger on it.
https://pastebin.com/7brF7ELn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dirty trick: use dbms_utility.format_call_stack to know who called your code:

```
create or replace trigger AUDITO_CUENTA_A
   after insert or update or delete on CUENTA_A
   for each row
 BEGIN
    if not dbms_utility.format_call_stack like ('%TR_MOVIMIENTO_A%') then
        IF inserting then
          INSERT INTO AUDI_CUENTA_A  VALUES  (:NEW.cod_CUENTA, :NEW.nom_cuenta, :OLD.SAL_CUENTA, :NEW.sal_cuenta, sysdate, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
        elsif deleting then
           INSERT INTO AUDI_CUENTA_A VALUES  (:NEW.cod_CUENTA, :NEW.nom_cuenta, :OLD.SAL_CUENTA, :NEW.sal_cuenta, sysdate, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
        elsif updating then
           INSERT INTO AUDI_CUENTA_A VALUES  (:NEW.cod_CUENTA, :NEW.nom_cuenta, :OLD.SAL_CUENTA, :NEW.sal_cuenta, sysdate, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
        END IF;
    end if;
 END;
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I had in mind but didn't know how to do it!, something like "if the `UPDATE` is coming from somewhere else than `MOVIMIENTO_A` do this..." initially I thought of putting like `after insert on CUENTA_A from MOVIMIENTO_A` but didn't work, this did the trick, thanks a lot.